# Function grid.raster returns NULL in R

Tags: r, raster, r-grid

I've been trying to do some raster image manipulation in R language using [grid package](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grid/html/grid-package.html). The problem is that I cannot retrive a return value from [grid.raster](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grid/html/grid.raster.html) function. When I do:

```
result <- grid.raster(inputData)
```

instead of "a rastergrob grob" (as specified in a documentation) I receive a `NULL` object.

I've double checked it with an example from the documentation:

```
redGradient <- matrix(hcl(0, 80, seq(50, 80, 10)), nrow=4, ncol=5)
grid.newpage()
result <- grid.raster(redGradient)
```

Still `result` is just a `NULL` object. Is R doing some return value interception here? If so, how can I get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `rasterGrob` function:

```
result <- rasterGrob(redGradient)
```

The two functions share a documentation page, but looking at the source, you can see that `grid.raster` creates the grob and then draws it, returning the value of `grid.draw` (`NULL`), whereas `rasterGrob` simply returns the grob.

Comment: I've totally missed that. Thanks! It seems that attention heat mapping actually makes sense.